# Hide foreign key column

Tags: jquery

I am tring to hide a foreign key column within an insert template.  The column is populated with jquery, but it would be nice if it was invisible. How is that done?  Thank you.

Comment: @Richard70: jQuery questions that aren't specific to SharePoint should be asked elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alex.  Are fk fields not used in SP?  Please let me know because I might need to make some changes.  I am storing the ID of the parent record in the item for filtering purposes.  Should this relationship be stored in a relationships table instead?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've managed to populate it with jQuery then have you tried simply setting the visibility of the object to "hidden"?

Comment: Thank you James.  This worked:   $("input[title='TaskOrderID']").hide();